# Logback RollingFileAppender file property doesn't recognize springProperty value

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I have problem with the configuration of Logback in my spring boot application. I've defined some spring properties that load their values dynamically from database but when I start the application only the property "log4j.adm.file" in tag "file" doesn't work. It's create a file "log4j.adm.file_IS_UNDEFINED" in the root path of the server but in tag "fileNamePattern" works perfect.

Any idea where is the problem? I attach my logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<springProperty name="logging.pattern.console" source="logging.pattern.console"/>

**<springProperty name="log4j.adm.file" source="log4j.adm.file"/>**
<springProperty name="log4j.adm.bck.number" source="log4j.adm.bck.number"/>
<springProperty name="log4j.adm.max.size" source="log4j.adm.max.size"/>
<springProperty name="log4j.adm.level" source="log4j.adm.level"/>

<appender name="FILE_ADMIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    **<file>${log4j.adm.file}</file>   ---> ERROR**
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        **<fileNamePattern>${log4j.adm.file}.%i</fileNamePattern>   --> OK**
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>${log4j.adm.bck.number}</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            ${logging.pattern.console}
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.xxxx.xxxx" level="${log4j.adm.nivel}" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_ADMIN" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

Comment: Try name a file explicitly - <file>file.log</file> - See if that works. Then you will at least know if it is the spring property or something else that fails

Comment: I had already tried it and works fine. The problem is when i put the springProperty :(

Comment: How is the spring property configured?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question... Do you mean how I load the value in the "source"?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem should be fixed using scope="context" in the  tag.